# Access tuple through index value in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I access the value of tuple through indexing in a template? When i try to do this....django gives me the error : Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'tuple[0]'.

template.html:

```
{{ tuple[0] }}
```

views.py:

```
def fun(request):
    tuple=('a','b','c','d')
    return render(request,'template.html',{'tuple':tuple})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply access tuple as in code below:

```
{{ tuple.0 }}
```

Also consider using [django built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) to iterate over your data, see simple usage below:

```
{% for item in tuple %}
    <span>
      {{ item }}
    </spam>
{% endfor %}
```